# Newly replaced brakes smoking

Tags: brakes

I just replaced my rear brakes on a 09 mustang ,and only one brake started smoking and had a bad smell. The smoking stopped but the smell is still there. Now the smell isnt to bad . I just need to know if there is anything wrong or will it go away? The brakes i put on are ceramic brakes.

Comment: If you replaced the rotors and did not de-grease them, that is the smoke/smell.

Comment: For additional piece of mind you can jack the rear of the car up again and make sure both wheels are turning freely.  I agree with the others that this is probably normal, but if one caliper/drum is not releasing properly it can heat up  quickly.

Answer (score 6):

If these are ceramic brakes, it's completely normal. I'm not sure why it happens, but I've seen it happen on almost every set of ceramic brakes which I've installed. The smoking will usually only happen once when they get hot enough, then they are basically "cured" and will be golden for the life of them. In other words, this should be nothing to worry about.